# How does an Enumerator object keep track of its state?

Tags: ruby

How does an instance of `Enumerator` keep track of its internal state? Take the following code snippet for example:

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  yielder << 1
  yielder << 2
  yielder << 3
end

puts enum.next # => 1
puts enum.next # => 2
enum.rewind # start again
puts enum.next # => 1
```

When an iterator method such as `each` is called on `enum`, it executes the block given to `each` once for every call to `yielder#<<` (or `yielder#yield`).

What I'm trying to understand is how Ruby makes `next` work. How does it remember the `next` value? How does it `rewind` back to the first one? If I were to code a basic implementation of how `next` works in Ruby, how would I do it?

Comment: Here's how: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerator.rb

Comment: In one word: fibers/coroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enumerator suspends execution internally and yields control to the caller. As Sergio says, it's fiber based, that is an execution unit more fine-grained than thread.

Fibers allow you do to this sort of thing:

```
def eat_more_fiber
  puts "In"
  Fiber.yield
  puts "Out"
end

f = Fiber.new do
  eat_more_fiber
end

f.resume
# Prints "In"
f.resume
# Prints "Out"
```

Note that after the first `resume` call control goes back to that block of code.

Comment: What about `Enumerator#rewind` then? How is it rewinded back to the first item?

Comment: @AsadMoosvi: do read the source code. All the answers are there. Hint: it simply reinitializes the yielder, using your block. Starts anew.